How to measure objects using python and the pyorbbecsdk library with depth cameras?
I have the FemtoMega depth camera which is supported by the orbbec SDK which also has a Python wrapper: https://github.com/orbbec/pyorbbecsdk. I am trying to create a python program that can measure the length, width, and height of objects (which will always be square/rectangle boxes). The following is what I was able to come up with using the examples in the SDK and help from ChatGPT, but I am not able to focus in on 1 object - I don't know what the camera is actually measuring. Could anyone please help me with this? There is very little information about doing something like this and coming from a JS background, I'm not sure how to proceed.
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyorbbecsdk import Config, OBSensorType, Pipeline, ColorFrame, FrameSet

ESC_KEY = 27
PRINT_INTERVAL = 1  # seconds
MIN_DEPTH = 20  # 20mm
MAX_DEPTH = 10000  # 10000mm


class TemporalFilter:
    def __init__(self, alpha):
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.previous_frame = None

    def process(self, frame):
        if self.previous_frame is None:
            result = frame
        else:
            result = cv2.addWeighted(frame, self.alpha, self.previous_frame, 1 - self.alpha, 0)
        self.previous_frame = result
        return result


def get_stream_dimensions(pipeline, sensor_type=OBSensorType.DEPTH_SENSOR):
    """
    Retrieves the dimensions (width, height) of the specified sensor's stream.

    :param pipeline: The Pipeline object.
    :param sensor_type: The sensor type (default is DEPTH_SENSOR).
    :return: Tuple (width, height) if successful, else (None, None).
    """
    profile_list = pipeline.get_stream_profile_list(sensor_type)
    if profile_list is None:
        print(f"No stream profiles found for sensor type: {sensor_type}")
        return None, None

    stream_profile = profile_list.get_default_video_stream_profile()
    if stream_profile is None:
        print(f"No default video stream profile found for sensor type: {sensor_type}")
        return None, None

    # Use getter methods instead of direct attribute access
    width = stream_profile.get_width()
    height = stream_profile.get_height()
    print(f"Stream Dimensions: {width}x{height}")
    return width, height


def print_sample_depth_values(depth_data, width, height):
    """
    Prints sample depth values from different regions of the frame.

    :param depth_data: Numpy array of depth data.
    :param width: Width of the depth frame.
    :param height: Height of the depth frame.
    """
    sample_points = [
        (0, 0),  # Top-left corner
        (height // 2, width // 2),  # Center
        (height - 1, width - 1),  # Bottom-right corner
        (height // 4, width // 4),  # Quarter position
        (3 * height // 4, 3 * width // 4)  # Three-quarters position
    ]

    print("Sample Depth Values:")
    for y, x in sample_points:
        distance = depth_data[y, x]
        print(f"  Point ({x}, {y}): {distance} mm")


def preprocess_depth_data(depth_data, lower_bound=MIN_DEPTH, upper_bound=MAX_DEPTH):
    """
    Applies preprocessing steps to the depth data, including thresholding.

    :param depth_data: Numpy array of raw depth data.
    :param lower_bound: Minimum depth to consider (in mm).
    :param upper_bound: Maximum depth to consider (in mm).
    :return: Preprocessed binary image for contour detection.
    """
    # Apply Gaussian Blur to reduce noise
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(depth_data, (5, 5), 0)

    # Apply binary thresholding based on depth bounds
    thresh = cv2.inRange(blurred, lower_bound, upper_bound)

    return thresh


def preprocess_color_data(color_frame):
    """
    Converts color frame to HSV and creates a mask to filter out the pallet.

    :param color_frame: ColorFrame object.
    :return: Binary mask where the pallet is masked out.
    """
    color_data = np.frombuffer(color_frame.get_data(), dtype=np.uint8)
    color_data = color_data.reshape((color_frame.get_height(), color_frame.get_width(), 3))
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(color_data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # Define the color range for the pallet (e.g., brown)
    lower_brown = np.array([10, 100, 20])
    upper_brown = np.array([20, 255, 200])

    # Create mask to exclude the pallet
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_brown, upper_brown)
    mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

    return mask_inv


def detect_and_calculate_dimensions(depth_data, depth_scale, min_contour_area=500):
    """
    Detects the largest object in the depth data and calculates its dimensions.

    :param depth_data: Numpy array of depth data.
    :param depth_scale: Scale factor to convert depth units to millimeters.
    :param min_contour_area: Minimum area to consider a contour valid.
    :return: Tuple containing dimensions dictionary and largest contour or None.
    """
    # Preprocess depth data
    thresh = preprocess_depth_data(depth_data)

    # Find contours to detect objects
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    if contours:
        # Filter out small contours based on area
        valid_contours = [cnt for cnt in contours if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > min_contour_area]
        if not valid_contours:
            print("No valid contours detected.")
            return None

        # Assume the largest valid contour corresponds to the object
        largest_contour = max(valid_contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(largest_contour)

        # Calculate center distance based on the bounding box center
        center_y = y + h // 2
        center_x = x + w // 2
        center_distance = depth_data[center_y, center_x]

        # Calculate object dimensions in millimeters
        object_width = w * depth_scale
        object_height = h * depth_scale

        dimensions = {
            "center_distance_mm": center_distance,
            "width_mm": object_width,
            "height_mm": object_height,
            "bounding_box": (x, y, w, h)
        }

        return dimensions, largest_contour
    else:
        print("No contours found.")
        return None


def main():
    config = Config()
    pipeline = Pipeline()
    temporal_filter = TemporalFilter(alpha=0.5)
    try:
        # Retrieve and enable the depth stream profile
        width, height = get_stream_dimensions(pipeline, OBSensorType.DEPTH_SENSOR)
        if width is None or height is None:
            print("Failed to get stream dimensions.")
            return

        profile_list = pipeline.get_stream_profile_list(OBSensorType.DEPTH_SENSOR)
        depth_profile = profile_list.get_default_video_stream_profile()
        print("Depth profile: ", depth_profile)

        # Use the retrieved stream profile to enable the stream
        config.enable_stream(depth_profile)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during stream configuration: {e}")
        return

    try:
        pipeline.start(config)
        last_print_time = time.time()
        while True:
            try:
                frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames(1000)
                if frames is None:
                    continue
                depth_frame = frames.get_depth_frame()
                if depth_frame is None:
                    continue

                # Convert depth frame data to numpy array
                depth_data = np.frombuffer(depth_frame.get_data(), dtype=np.uint16)
                depth_data = depth_data.reshape((height, width))

                # Apply scaling and filtering
                depth_scale = depth_frame.get_depth_scale()
                depth_data = depth_data.astype(np.float32) * depth_scale
                depth_data = np.where((depth_data > MIN_DEPTH) & (depth_data < MAX_DEPTH), depth_data, 0)
                depth_data = depth_data.astype(np.uint16)

                # Apply temporal filtering
                depth_data = temporal_filter.process(depth_data)

                # Detect object and calculate dimensions
                result = detect_and_calculate_dimensions(depth_data, depth_scale)
                if result:
                    dimensions, largest_contour = result
                    center_distance = dimensions["center_distance_mm"]
                    object_width = dimensions["width_mm"]
                    object_height = dimensions["height_mm"]

                    # Print dimensions at defined intervals
                    current_time = time.time()
                    if current_time - last_print_time >= PRINT_INTERVAL:
                        print(f"Center distance: {center_distance} mm")
                        print(f"Object Width: {object_width:.2f} mm")
                        print(f"Object Height: {object_height:.2f} mm")
                        last_print_time = current_time

                    # Draw bounding box and center point on the depth image
                    depth_image = cv2.normalize(depth_data, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
                    depth_image = cv2.applyColorMap(depth_image, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
                    x, y, w, h = dimensions["bounding_box"]
                    cv2.rectangle(depth_image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                    center_y = y + h // 2
                    center_x = x + w // 2
                    cv2.circle(depth_image, (center_x, center_y), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
                else:
                    center_distance = 0
                    print("No objects detected.")

                # Display the depth image with annotations
                cv2.imshow("Depth Viewer", depth_image)
                key = cv2.waitKey(1)
                if key == ord('q') or key == ESC_KEY:
                    print("Exiting the program.")
                    break
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("Interrupted by user.")
                break
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred during streaming: {e}")
    finally:
        pipeline.stop()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        print("Pipeline stopped and windows closed.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


